# I keep getting SyntaxError and I don't know why

Tags: python, syntax

This is my code:

```
29 for i, j in enumerate(self.noun):
30      if j in self.c:
31          try:
32              k = j + self.noun[i + 1]
33              if k in c:
34                  self.letters.append(k)
35                  if k in self.unp:
36                      self.letstat.append("CN")
37                  elif k in self.pr:
38                      self.letstat.append("CP")
39                  else:
40                      self.letstat.append("CA")
41                      
42          self.letters.append(j)
43          if j in self.unp:
44              self.letstat.append("CN")
45          elif j in self.pr:
46              self.letstat.append("CP")
47          else:
48              self.letstat.append("CA")
49      else:
50          try:
51              if j == "i" and self.noun[i - 1] in self.pr:
52                  continue
53          self.letters.append(j)
54          self.letstat.append("V")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\programming\Python\yisib\main.py", line 1, in <module>                                      
from nouns import Noundec                                                                                             
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\programming\Python\yisib\nouns.py", line 42                                                 
self.letters.append(j)                                                                                                  
^                                                                                                                   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please tell me what i did wrong? I've checked the code 7 times, and i don't seem to have missed any bracket or indent. Thanks

Comment: lacking your `except` from `try`

Comment: As the answer below says, you have `try` without `except` or `finally`. But why do you have `try` at all? I think the solution here is to remove `try:` at line 31 and unindent the following lines from 32 to 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some `except` or `finally` when using `try`:

```
try:
    if j == "i" and self.noun[i - 1] in self.pr:
        continue
except IndexError:
    pass

self.letters.append(j)
```

Question is: why? Are you expecting an `IndexError` ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using a bare `except`, that's going to silently going to catch things like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` if the user tries to quit the program. I would definitely only have it catch `IndexError`.

Comment: @Jasmijn: True.

Comment: thanks, i wanted it that when it gets to the last object in the list, for the (current object's index) + 1 to not give an error. i've corrected that part of the code, thanks for answering though.